# Getting the top ranked records in group by count of related records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a schema like so:

- **`matches`**

  - `id`
  - `opponent`, ...etc
- **`players`**

  - `id`
  - `name`, ...etc
- **`votes`**

  - `id`
  - `match_id` (fk: `matches`)
  - `player_id` (fk: `players`)
  - `type` ("up" or "down")

I'd like get the top ranked `player` based on the count of votes grouped by match.

desired output:

```
| match_id | opponent | top_upvoted_player_id | top_downvoted_player_id |
|----------|----------|-----------------------|-------------------------|
| 1        | foo      | 88                    | 55                      |
| 2        | bar      | 77                    | 88                      |
| 3        | baz      | 88                    | 99                      |
```

I've started with a CTE like so:

```
with vote_counts as (
    SELECT
        votes.match_id AS match_id,
        votes.player_id,
        votes.type,
        count(votes.id) AS vote_count
    FROM
        votes
    GROUP BY
        votes.type,
        votes.player_id,
        votes.match_id
)
```

but I'm not sure where to go next.

I'm thinking I need a `RANK` statement in my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like get the top ranked player based on the count of votes grouped by match.

You are on the right track, aggregating by player, match, and type.  You then want an additional level of aggregation at the match level to get the players with the maximum up and down votes.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT m.match_id, m.opponent,
       MAX(pmt.player_id) FILTER (WHERE pmt.type = 'up' AND seqnum = 1) as player_most_up_votes,
       MAX(pmt.player_id) FILTER (WHERE pmt.type = 'down' AND seqnum = 1) as player_most_down_votes
FROM (SELECT v.player_id, v.match_id, v.type,
             COUNT(*) as votes,
             COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE v.type = 'up') AS up_votes,
             COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE v.type = 'down') AS down_votes,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY v.match_id, v.type,  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM votes v
      GROUP BY v.player_id, v.match_id, v.type
     ) pmt JOIN
     matches m
     ON pmt.match_id = m.match_id
GROUP BY pmt.match_id;
```